# How to set up Emacs with Clozure CL but without SLIME

Tags: subprocess, common-lisp, clojure

I want to manually set up my own Emacs CL environment on Mac OS X 7 without the SLIME package i.e. it will only use Clozure CL.

To put it other way, I want to use the Emacs CL just like I use the "Inferior Emacs Lisp Mode" (`M-x` `ielm`) but instead of the plain old Emacs Lisp, it'll use the Clozure CL.

So I've downloaded Emacs-24.4 installed it under the `/Applications` and Clozure CL 1.6 under the `/Users/macmini/ccl-1.6` and edited the `~/.emacs` to have:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/Users/macmini/ccl-1.6/dx86cl64")
```

I then restarted Emacs to start to use the Clozure CL but I couldn't use it. Can someone show how to use Clozure CL? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `run-lisp`.
Afterwards, you can use e.g.

- <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> (`lisp-load-file`) to eval a source file.
- <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd> (`lisp-eval-defun`) to eval a statement.

Still, I can't imagine why someone wouldn't want to run SLIME.

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer. It solved the question. I wouldn't guess or find that "run-lisp" would do the thing, I will look it up on the manual.

Ultimately I want to run SLIME but I chose step by step approach. Here's my question on how to set up SLIME, if you'd like to see: [link](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4091/trouble-setting-up-emacs-slime-on-powerpc-mac)