# Trouble setting up Emacs SLIME on PowerPC Mac

Tags: osx, slime

I've downloaded and installed Emacs 24.1 on my PowerPC Mac and it works perfectly. And I've just added the Clozure CL to it and that works perfectly too using [this tutorial](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/how-to-set-up-emacs-with-clozure-cl-but-without-slime). Now, I want to use SLIME. So I installed the SLIME package by:

1. `M-x` `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd>
2. `slime` <kbd>RET</kbd>

SLIME seems to have installed itself into the directory `~/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20141126.1323`. So, I added the following code to my `~/.emacs`:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/Users/haansgruber/lisp/ccl-1.6/dppccl")
;; slime
(add-to-list 'load-path "Users/haansgruber/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20141126.1323")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
```

Then, restarted Emacs to see SWANK loaded SLIME but nothing happened. I entered:

`M-x` `slime`

But, this time it gave an error and fell back to *inferior-lisp* which is Clozure CL as shown below:

[image: Emacs 24.1 PowerPC Mac]

There must be some wrong lines on the `.emacs` config file. There are different `.emacs` conf lines available on the Internet and I tried several of them and they all ended up more or less with the same error, so I gave up. Could you help me find the solution?

Comment: This looks like the version of SLIME you are installing is older or in some other way incompatible with CCL version you have. I would ask on SLIME's mailing list what version should be used with what version of CCL. Usually, this isn't a problem but eventually a Lisp may add or remove a feature SLIME depends on and things like this happen.

Comment: Wait, what is even stranger is that SLIME tries to load a fasl with the code that gives this error... how did it manage to compile it in the first place? Can you try deleting (or just moving temporarily) ccl.dfsl and see if it will try to recompile it?

Comment: I am having the same problem you reporter about Slime with Clozure.
I see that you have been able to solve it with sbcl.
But how about Clozure? Have you been able to make it work with Slime? Thanks

Comment: On my OSX Lion, I use CMUCL because it works the best. On PowerPC Mac I keep on using SBCL. No luck with Clozure CL on OSX Lion or PowerPC Leopard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that works starts off with the lines [abo-abo](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2094/abo-abo) has given, that is

downloading the SLIME package:

```
cd ~/git
git clone https://github.com/slime/slime
```

and adding these to `~/.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/git/slime")
(require 'slime-autoloads)
```

and additionally add this line to `~/.emacs`, assuming sbcl is installed into `/usr/local/bin`

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/local/bin/sbcl")
```

If you only do the above, you end up with an Emacs running SLIME on the background. To have the SLIME come to the foreground you should add these lines to `~/.emacs`

Source: [franz.com/emacs/slime.lhtml](http://franz.com/emacs/slime.lhtml)

```
(eval-after-load "slime"
  '(progn
    (add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/slime/contrib")
    (slime-setup '(slime-fancy slime-banner))
    (setq slime-complete-symbol*-fancy t)
    (setq slime-complete-symbol-function 'slime-fuzzy-complete-symbol)))
```

Having added those lines, restarted Emacs and entered `M-x` `slime` I finally got what I wanted:
[image: Emacs Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [hizliresim.com](https://i.hizliresim.com/122VBj.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

SLIME from `package-install` can be finicky at times.

Instead:

```
cd ~/git
git clone https://github.com/slime/slime
```

and:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/git/slime")
(require 'slime-autoloads)
```

After this, <kbd>M-x slime</kbd>. It will take a short time to compile
before the first run. Try sbcl if Clozure doesn't work (I'm using sbcl and I just installed it on my laptop).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, it couldn't even load SLIME. Here's what I did:

'code' mkdir cd ~/git, mkdir slime, cd slime, 
curl -fsSLk https://github.com/slime/slime/tarball/master | tar xz -m --strip 1

and added the 2 lines you've given to ~/.emacs deleted the lines about SLIME.

I have also uninstalled Emacs and installed it from scratch to remove the previous SLIME inst. 

Started Emacs and it gave this error on startup:

File error: Cannot open load file, slime-autoloads

Commented that line, restarted.

M-x slime returned [No match]

Comment: The file needs to be at `~/git/slime/slime-autoloads.el`. Is this the case?

Comment: After you mentioned the presence of ~/git/slime/slime-autoload.el, I've once more checked with it and noticed I've mistyped it on .emacs file. Corrected it and restarted Emacs. But again the familiar error came up, here's the screenshot.[link](http://i.hizliresim.com/D8XvQz.png)

Comment: I've installed SBCL v1.0.47 (proper for PPC Mac) It installed itself into /usr/local/bin/sbcl so I changed the line to 

(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usrlocal/bin/sbcl")
and restarted Emacs. Entering M-x slime returned: 

Process inferior-lisp not running. I might be missing some other declarative line for sbcl, I don't know.

Comment: What's wrong with Emacs 24.3 or 24.4? It could possibly have less problems by upgrading to those versions.

Comment: There'a limit for PowerPC Macs. I've tried downloading 24.4 but it didn't run on PPC Mac. 24.1 worked so I sticked with it. Haven't tried 24.3 yet.

Comment: `Process inferior-lisp not running` means that it can't find the executable. Did you mis-spell it?

Comment: Yes you're correct I mis-spelled the path, instead of /usr/local, I had written /usrlocal. After correction SLIME looked like loading and several tens of files compiling but in the end I think it again fell to inferior lisp mode, not SLIME mode. Here's the pic (http://i.hizliresim.com/z2RXY9.png)

Comment: Your setup should now be fine. Try to restart Emacs. If that doesn't work, upgrade to 24.3.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that this setup is not fine. Here's a comparison picture I made on an Intel Mac for which Lisp in a Box (Lisp with SLIME preconfigured and as such available as a download) pic. (http://i.hizliresim.com/312v74.png) The one on the left I set up manually , the one on the right is the Lisp in a Box setup. You see, when I enter an expression SLIME gives the details of it at the bottom whereas my own setup doesn't give. I have to set up my own SLIME as there's no Lisp in a Box for PowerPC and I need to use SLIME on my PowerPC Mac.